# Maven assembly Plugin with Maven Jar Plugin

Tags: maven-2, assemblies, jar

I'm trying to use the maven assembly plugin for the first time. Essentially, I want to combine the output of the maven assembly plugin with that of the maven jar plugin into the target/classes directory so I can still run the app within Eclipse.

I couldn't find a way to tell the maven jar plugin to collect the output of the maven assembly plugin. Similarly, I found no way to tell assembly plugin to put its output into target/classes.

The closes i cam to a solution was to tell assembly plugin to output its result into classes.dir directory.  The suffix 'dir' is the format used while 'classes' is the finalName define in the plugin configuration.

I was hoping that directory-single would force assembly plugin to ignore the format and hence, output in the classes directory. This doesn't work for me; am i misinterpreting the description of this goal?

How would you guys solve this issue? Below is my assembly plugin declaration in the pom as well as my descriptor:

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2-beta-1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>package</id>
                    <goals>
                         <goal>directory-single</goal> 
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <finalName>classes</finalName>

                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>descriptor.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


     <assembly>
     <files>
    <file>
        <source>${repository-path}</source>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <filtered>true</filtered>
        <destName>repository.xml</destName>
    </file>
    </files>
    <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
         <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
    </fileSet>
   </fileSets>
  </assembly>
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Could you explain this fist please? Then, we'll see if there is a solution. But for now, what you're trying to achieve is really not clear to me.

Comment: Thanks, let me reformulate.

1) The primary reason why i use assembly plugin is to rename some files during the build process. I have different versions of files fro QA, Prod, and Dev and this should be tramsparent to the app.

Now, the assembly plugin solves this problem. But the problem that it creates is that I can't find a way to put the generated files in target/classes folder such that the app can read it the same way it would do in Prod. 

So, simply put, how do i tell assembly plugin to put the processed data into target/classes instead of target/classes.dir?

Comment: Aren't profiles an option? Managing environment specific stuff is a good use case for profiles (combined with filtering).

Comment: They cannot be filtered directly as the content is big and differs widely. The workaround is to put the name of this config file in another file and then filter this latter file. Which means the app will need to read the second file to determine which config file it needs to read. There must be a much simpler solution.

Comment: Can't you include one or the other (using the same name) depending on which profile you use? Really, you should update your question with the exact problem you want to solve.

Answer (score 1):

> That's exactly what i am trying to do. How would you do that? That is you have two files Dev.xml and Prod.xml and you want to include them as Config.xml depending on the profile.

You could use the maven-antrun-plugin and profiles to delete/copy/rename configuration files depending on the target environment (this is one solution). Have a look at [Building For Different Environments with Maven 2](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html), this guide shows precisely how to achieve this.